# Why do my JavaScript calls not work in a form after switching the doctype to HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that uses JavaScript to reveal additional fields depending on user selections. The code worked fine using the XHTML 1.1 doctype (not my choice... lame school project guidelines), but after switching to the HTML5 doctype nothing works. The only way I can get any JavaScript to work inside the form is to put it directly in the `onchange=""` setting; just adding the function call there will not work. I've tried event listeners also, and that doesn't work either.

For simplicity's sake I'm only showing code for one of the dynamic fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<?php include "phpself.php"; ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("visitor").addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
        Visitor();
        });

function Visitor() {
    var visitor = document.getElementById("visitor").value;

    if (visitor=="Other") {
        var othertext="<label>What would you consider yourself?</label><br/><input type="text" name="other_visitor" id="other_visitor"/>";
        document.getElementById("vother").innerHTML=(othertext);
    }
}
</script>
</head><body>

<form action=\"".getPHPSelf()."\" enctype="text/plain" method="post" onsubmit="return FormValid();" >

<fieldset style="width=50%;">
<legend>Comments</legend>
    <label>I am a:</label>
        <select name="visitor" id="visitor" onchange="Visitor();">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">select...</option>
        <option value="Friend">Friend</option>  
        <option value="Client">Client</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    <br/><br/><div id="vother"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

I'm aware that other people have asked similar questions, but none of the answers I've found work for me.

Comment: your script is loaded first , at that time DOM is not rendered, so no events are bound, Keep your script at the bottom, it will work

Comment: Moving the JavaScript to the bottom had no effect. Either way, that would only affect the event listener and not the `onchange` call, which worked flawlessly before the switch to the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Check your console for errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified some issues in your code:

1. this line is not valid (*syntax error*):

   ```
   var othertext="<label>What would you consider yourself?</label><br/><input type="text" name="other_visitor" id="other_visitor"/>";
   ```

   You should **escape** the *double quotes*, or replace them with *single quotes*.

   This will work:

   ```
   var othertext = "<label>What would you consider yourself?</label><br/><input type=text name='other_visitor' id='other_visitor' />";
   ```
2. Get rid of the  inline `onchange="Visitor();` binder or the `document.getElementById("visitor").addEventListener`. You should choose one of the approachs.
3. move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of your body (just before `</body>`). Or wrap your code into [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event (IE9+).
4. (optional). You don't need parenthesis around `(othertext)` here:

   ```
   document.getElementById("vother").innerHTML = (othertext);
   ```

#### Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/txk11m6c/

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it misses the point of the question. The code does not perform the call as it should. I even had an `alert();` as the first line of the function and that would not show unless I put code to call the function outside the `<form>`.

Comment: @Sienile sorry, but which function are you talking about? which call? if you check the fiddle, the new input is shown now (it wasn't). I edited with one more item: choose one event binder approach.

Comment: @Sienile the JavaScript syntax error will prevent any of the scripts in that `<script>` block from being parses. It is **not** a runtime error

Comment: Wow... It did actually work. I've never had JavaScript refuse to run an entire function (or even the very first line of one) because of an error halfway through it. I guess the JS interpreting for HTML5 is a lot more heavy handed in its handling of syntax errors.

Comment: actually, what happened is what @Phil commented. Syntax error is thrown when the interpreter encounters invalid code while parsing it. The script execution is then terminated.

Comment: I get that. I'm just confused as to why the same code running in the same browser behaved radically different when I changed the doctype to HTML5. Non-HTML5 JavaScript will process until it gets to the bad line and then fail to process the remainder of the script, rather than refuse to execute the entire script. ... Lesson learned, double check my double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your script at bottom like given below or use window.onload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<?php include "phpself.php"; ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

</head><body>

<form action=\"".getPHPSelf()."\" enctype="text/plain" method="post" onsubmit="return FormValid();" >

<fieldset style="width=50%;">
<legend>Comments</legend>
    <label>I am a:</label>
        <select name="visitor" id="visitor" onchange="Visitor();">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">select...</option>
        <option value="Friend">Friend</option>  
        <option value="Client">Client</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    <br/><br/><div id="vother"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("visitor").addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
        Visitor();
        });

function Visitor() {
    var visitor = document.getElementById("visitor").value;

    if (visitor=="Other") {
        var othertext="<label>What would you consider yourself?</label><br/><input type="text" name="other_visitor" id="other_visitor"/>";
        document.getElementById("vother").innerHTML=(othertext);
    }
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<?php include "phpself.php"; ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // ~ F I X ~ Run code when the rest of page is done loading instead of immediately when browser reads it. This is a very common problem I've noticed newbies have with JS

        document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",this); // Remove event after it's served purpose
        document.getElementById("visitor").addEventListener("change", Visitor); // Also removed redundant function, Visitor can already be called by itself

        function Visitor() {
            var visitor = document.getElementById("visitor").value;

            if (visitor=="Other") {
                var othertext="<label>What would you consider yourself?</label><br/><input type=\"text\" name=\"other_visitor\" id=\"other_visitor\"/>"; // Backslashed quotations that were clearly meant to be included part of string
                document.getElementById("vother").innerHTML=(othertext);
            }
        }

    });

</script>
</head><body>

<form action=\"".getPHPSelf()."\" enctype="text/plain" method="post" onsubmit="return FormValid();" >

<fieldset style="width=50%;">
<legend>Comments</legend>
    <label>I am a:</label>
        <select name="visitor" id="visitor">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">select...  </option>
    <option value="Friend">Friend</option>  
    <option value="Client">Client</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
<br/><br/><div id="vother"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for posting a full answer! Could you please add a explanation around what the fix entailed? Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: To be fair, he did explain his changes via comments within the code. However, it's easy to miss them as most comments start beyond the edges of the text box.